# How do I write a Python class taking other super class objects as parameters

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Lets assume that I have a class called Person, and a class that inherits this called Group.  Person has an attribute called name and one called age.  When I create a Group I want to pass n person objects and their new name is a combo of names, and their new age is their combined age.

also for the hell of it, going to keep track of how many people, and how many groups there are separately (just so inheriting makes any sense in this example.)

```
class Person:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = make_person() # count is also the person's id in this example

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Name: {self.name} Age: {self.age}'

    @classmethod
    def make_person(cls):
        cls.count += 1
        return cls.count

class Group(Person):
    def __init__(self, *people):
        #not sure how to do this, Below Does Not Work, something like
        new_name = self.make_group(people)
        new_age = self.new_age(people)
        self.name = new_name
        self.age = new_age
        super().__init__(self.new_name, self.new_age)

    def make_group(self, *people):
        return (' & ').join([person.name for person in People])

    def new_age(self, *people):
        return sum([person.age for person in people])
```

then you would think i could write

```
anne = Person('Anne', 20)
bob = Person('Bob', 20)
carl = person('Carl', 25)

couple = Group(anne, bob)
threesome = Group(anne, bob, carl)

print(couple)
print(threesome)
```

but this doesnt work.  For some reason the group class isnt getting the people object i pass, or i'm defining it wrong...any ideas?

Comment: That's not what inheritance means. `class Group(Person)` says that a group is a kind of person. A group isn't a kind of person, so it shouldn't inherit that way.

Comment: what, exactly, 'doesn't work'? As noted, this is not a good use-case for inheritance, but in any case, it isn't clear to me what you were expecting.

Answer (score -1):

What you have written is that a `Group` is a particular type of `Person`.  This doesn't seem quite right to me.  Regardless, here is a version that will run and give the desired output:

```
class Person:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = Person.make_person() # count is also the person's id in this example

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Name: {self.name} Age: {self.age}'

    @classmethod
    def make_person(cls):
        cls.count += 1
        return cls.count

class Group(Person):
    def __init__(self, *people):
        #not sure how to do this, Below Does Not Work, something like
        new_name = self.make_group(*people)
        new_age = self.new_age(*people)
        self.name = new_name
        self.age = new_age
        super().__init__(self.name, self.age)

    def make_group(self, *people):
        return (' & ').join([person.name for person in people])

    def new_age(self, *people):
        return sum([person.age for person in people])

anne = Person('Anne', 20)
bob = Person('Bob', 20)
carl = Person('Carl', 25)

couple = Group(anne, bob)
threesome = Group(anne, bob, carl)

print(couple)
print(threesome)
```

Changes from your code:

- some typos with capital letters
- put a `*` before `people` when passing it
- take care of variable scope